# Please help me in understanding this Recursion Question

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, frontend

I am not understanding how this function is working if I have passed array  and value of n as 5 then

```
return multiply([1,2,3,4,5],4)*arr[4]
```

this is the first line that is going to happen in this function process.

Can anyone explain me this line.

```
function multiply(arr, n) {

        if (n <= 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1];
        }
    }
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//calling function
    multiply(a, 5);
```

Comment: I've edited your question. Please pay attention to formatting and unnecessary capitalization so your question is more readable. There's no need for caps lock and yelling.

Comment: Try the function "on the paper" - write what is going on and how the data looks like each call. Or try to put some `console.log` to see what is `arr`, `n-1` and `arr[n-1]`

Comment: `multiply` eventually returns `1` which means that you'll end up with something like this: `((((1 * 1) * (1 * 2)) * (1 * 3)) * (1 * 4)) * 5`

Answer (score 1):

This function multiplies first two elements of the array and then their product is multiplied with the next element in the array. This goes on until the index, equal to the number that is passed to the function as a second argument, is reached in the array.

If the second argument is greater than the length of the array, you will get `NaN` as a result.

Here's the breakdown of each recursive call:

**first call:**

arguments: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n = 5

return:    multiply(arr, 4) * a[4]

**second call:**

arguments: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n = 4

return:    multiply(arr, 3) * a[3]

**third call:**

arguments: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n = 3

return:    multiply(arr, 2) * a[2]

**fourth call:**

arguments: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n = 2

return:    multiply(arr, 1) * a[1]

**fifth call:**

arguments: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n = 1

return:    multiply(arr, 0) * a[0]

**sixth call:**

arguments: arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], n = 0

return:    1

Last recursive call (sixth call) returns 1.

So fifth call takes the return value of sixth call and returns `multiply(arr, 0) * a[0] = 1 * 1 = 1`.

Fourth call takes the return value of fifth call and returns `multiply(arr, 1) * a[1] = 1 * 2 = 2`.

third call takes the return value of fourth call and returns `multiply(arr, 2) * a[2] = 2 * 3 = 6`.

Second call takes the return value of third call and returns `multiply(arr, 3) * a[3] = 6 * 4 = 24`.

first call takes the return value of second call and returns `multiply(arr, 4) * a[4] = 24 * 5 = 120`.